# Mix pure function with side effect in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a simple api method:

```
def addWishToBoard(wish: Wish, boardId: BoardId, userId: UserId): Option[Board]
```

It adds wish to board, if `boardId` and `userId` matches.

Boards are stored simply in a list:

```
private var boards = List.empty[Board]
```

I use var here in order to simulate side effect.

The implementation code:

```
def addWishToBoard(wish: Wish, boardId: BoardId, userId: UserId): Option[Board] = {
    val board = find(boardId)
      .filter(_.ownerId == userId)
      .map(board => board.copy(wishes = wish :: board.wishes.toList))

    board.foreach(b => boards = b :: boards)

    board
  }
```

Is there functional way to implement this side effect without using val for board? How can I compose side effect that returns `Unit` and pure function that returns `Option[Board]` ?

Comment: boards.foreach(board => boards = board :: boards) do you mean board.foreach(b => boards = b :: boards)?

Comment: @Ivan yes I meant `board.foreach(b => boards = b :: boards)` I will update to don't confuse reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept a function that will be called if we manage to produce a board.

```
def addWishToBoard(wish: Wish, boardId: BoardId, userId: UserId)(sideEffect: Board => Board = identity): Option[Board] = 
  find(boardId)
  .filter(_.ownerId == userId)
  .map(board => sideEffect(board.copy(wishes = wish :: board.wishes.toList)))
```

you could also use option's `fold`

```
def addWishToBoard(wish: Wish, boardId: BoardId, userId: UserId): Option[Board] = 
  find(boardId)
  .filter(_.ownerId == userId)
  .map(board =>board.copy(wishes = wish :: board.wishes.toList))
  .fold(None){v => 
    sideEffect(v) 
    Some(v)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here ... 
There are plenty of ways to write this without using `val`. For example:

```
boards
  .find(boardId)
  .filter(_.ownerId == userId)
  .map(board => board.copy(wishes = wish :: board.wishes.toList))
  .map(b => boards = b :: boards; b)
```

Or, perhaps,

```
def addBoard(b: Board) = {
  boards = b :: boards
  b
}


 boards
  .find(boardId)
  .filter(_.ownerId == userId)
  .map(board => board.copy(wishes = wish :: board.wishes.toList))
  .map(addBoard)
```

(BTW, you keep adding "versions" of the same board to to the list with this function, without removing the previous copy - that doesn't seem to make very much sense).

Comment: First of all I am finding board in board list by boardId, after that I check is current userId matches owner id(is user is owner of this board). If it is, I change this board by adding wish to it, and after that I update board list with new board list. It is artificial thing to demonstrate a side effect operation, in this case assignment to variable.

Comment: I know you are doing that :)
I am just saying, that if you add two wishes to the same board, you will end up with three versions of that board in your list, containing 0, 1, and two wishes respectively.

Answer (score -2):

```
scala> case class Board()
defined class Board

scala> val ob = Option.empty[Board]
ob: Option[Board] = None
```

Then define the following

```
scala> implicit class AnyOps[A](val any: A) extends AnyVal {
     | def tap(effect: A => Unit): A = { effect(any); any }
     | }
defined class AnyOps
```

Then use it

```
scala> ob.tap(println)
None
res9: Option[Board] = None
```

From a functional programming perspective, side effects should be done via `IO`; something like:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._; import effect._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import effect._

scala>  OptionT(ob.point[IO]) >>! { b =>
 |        IO.putStrLn(b.toString).liftM[OptionT]
 |      }
res12: scalaz.OptionT[scalaz.effect.IO,Board] = 
OptionT(scalaz.effect.IO$$anon$7@3fd8d23d)
```

The return type here (of course) encapsulates the effect. However, I strongly suspect that your program will need a lot of re-writing in order to *be functional* (i.e. to have no `var`s anywhere), so the `tap` solution is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Bit puzzled as to the downvotes without comments as to why?